# GitLab file variable with a dot or period `.` in its name?

Tags: gitlab

I have a file called `.auto.tfvars` that I want to use to set some Terraform variables in an CI run, however when I try to add it, I get a popup called,

> Variables key can contain only letters, digits and '_'.

Looking at the documentation for [GitLab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-file-type-cicd-variables), I don't see this restriction mentioned nor a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitLab file variable name isn't the path to the file. **It's the name of an environmental variable that stores the path to the file**. Either way you'll have to move the key to where you want the file stored.

Let's say you set this in the GitLab UI,

```
MYGITLAB_FILE_VARIABLE=contents
```

When that gets run `MYGITLAB_FILE_VARIABLE` will be some long and random path name on the runner. You'll have to run this in a CI job to get that file where you want.

```
mv $MYGITLAB_FILE_VARIABLE /my/desired/path
```

Answer (score 0):

I used double __ and renamed them to dots during the pipeline process.
Its not ideal but works

`env |sed 's/__/./g' > application.properties`